# Autocomplete of python code does not work with custom docker container for databricks runtime

Tags: python, docker, databricks

I've setted up a custom docker container for databricks but for python there's no autocomplete (works for scala).

This is my container:

```
FROM databricksruntime/standard:9.x

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install build-essential \
  nvidia-cuda-toolkit \
  libpython3.8-dev


ADD requirements.txt .
RUN /databricks/python3/bin/pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN /databricks/python3/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

What I'm missing?
Thanks in advance!